# Setting up a IPv6 Darknet/Network Telescope

Tags: internet, ipv6

I would like to setup a IPv6 Darknet/Network Telescope. It is unused address space a network that is completely passive and sends no outbound traffic. [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjva6ZJyhwE) gives more details.

Most residential IPv6 internet connections get a /64 subnet. Considering with IPv6 there is not NAT in the way it seems like it would be a great opportunity to setup a darket/network telescope.

I have searched online but I have not found any resources to setup an IPv6 darknet/network telescope on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed such "telescopes" as part of passive network monitoring (company work, not available publicly). I did not find anything readily available but then I had some specific needs as well.

You can start with running a `tcpdump` on that address, getting rid of the predictable noise and the listen for what is addressed specifically to your address.

Comment: How do I use tcpdump to monitor a whole /64 subnet?

Comment: @JohnThomson: you won't - I was mentioning a solution which does not require BGP announcements. The problem with these announcements is that you need cooperation from border servers, otherwise your announcement will be rejected. In my case I had access to very dispersed LANs and many Internet PoP so having one IP in each of these places listening was fine.

Comment: @JohnThomson: and BTW the video is very interesting, particularly the historical aspects.